# jquery datepicker onselect year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am selecting only year from drop down. Here is my code:

```
$('#year1').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    dateFormat: 'yy',
    yearRange: "-2:+0",
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 1, 1));
    }
});
```

Now I want to close the panel when I select year from drop down. But it does not close on selecting year. But when I click anywhere else it gets closed. I tried `onSelect` insted of `onClose` event but this event does not fire on selecting year. I think this event fires on selecting date. Can anyone help me close it when I select only year from down down.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`onChangeMonthYear`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear) option to run your function when the user selects a year from dropdown. Then you can use [`hide()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-hide) method to "close" the picker.

Here a code sample:

```js
$('#year1').datepicker( {
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: false,
  dateFormat: 'yy',
  yearRange: "-2:+0",
  onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst){
    // Set date to picker
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 1, 1));
    // Hide (close) the picker
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
    // Blur to let the picker open on focus in
    $(this).blur();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="year1">
```